# Second option if str.index does not exist

Tags: python

if I have a str and the I use `str.index(char)` and the char does not exist, is it possible with one line to assign another char to the variable?

Maybe like this

```
str = "bar/foo"

t = str.index("_") | "Empty"
```

`str` dosen't contain _ , so the string "Empty" should be assigned instead.

Comment: I recommend not using `str` as a variable name as it is a builtin and will cause you much pain down the road.

Comment: @theorifice it was just for illustration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index) would throw a `ValueError` if substring is not in a string, wrap it into an if/else checking the presence of substring in a string via `in` operator:

```
>>> s = "bar/foo"
>>> s.index("_") if "_" in s else "Empty"
"Empty"

>>> s = "bar_foo"
>>> s.index("_") if "_" in s else "Empty"
3
```